# How to get overall line count in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to get an overall line count of a large file (hundreds of thousands of lines) in python. My question is how do I count the overall line without counting the special characters? I only need the lines with numbers in X, Y, dx and dy.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y57Zy.jpg)

This is my approach so far but it includes all lines. I don't have to count the lines with special characters

```
with open('frequency_map.e00000.fm', 'r') as f:
    line_count = 0
    for line in f:
        line_count += 1

print(line_count)
```

Comment: Probably use `csv.reader` and check `all(line)` to see if there are no empty cells.  Impossible to say for sure without any actual data.

Comment: Can you please look at the example I posted. And if you can write it out for me it will be great. I'm new to python.

Comment: A photograph of a hand-drawn example is not enough information about the structure of your file to understand it. Is it a csv file?  An excel file?  Some other non-text format? Please include a few example lines from the file in question, and your current attempt at solving it.

Comment: Your best bet would be to try to code it yourself, or you won't learn anything from it. Here's the module Patrick is referring to, which is a good starting point: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your description, you can just exclude any line with a literal `"*"` in it. There is no need to parse the csv: `"*" in line` tests whether the character appears.

A `sum` over all lines *not* matching this condition is sufficient, then:

```
with open('frequency_map.e00000.fm', 'r') as f:
    line_count = sum(1 for line in f if '*' not in line)
    #            |   |               \ valid lines do not have a "*" in them
    #            |   \ add 1 for every valid line
    #            \ sum over all lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
file_handle = open('frequency_map.e00000.fm', 'r')
newlines=len(file_handle.readlines())
print('There are %d lines in the file.' % (newlines))
```